# How do i fix the broken thumbnails from a wordpress migration?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Let me give a bit of context:
I migrated my blog to a new hosting provider, when i finally exported all my posts i realized that all my images where missing. I entered to my wp-conten/uploads folder and found nothing.

What i did is to manually upload my folders with images to this folder using ftp file manager, and volià my images where now displaying in my blog, i synced the uploads forlder with my media library using Bulk Media Register and everything is working fine...except for the thumbnails.

How can i re-link my broken thumbnails if i don't wanna do it manually editing post by post?
I have tried Media Sync, Force Regenerate Thumbnails, and Regenerate Thumbnails plugins with no luck

Comment: Run a search replace on the database.

Comment: Have you tried to [reset the thumbnail settings](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78542/223934) in your [media settings](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-media-screen/)?.